# AutoPreview in Advanced Find Window

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2007 AutoPreview worked.  In Outlook 2010 AutoPreview does not show the message contents.  Has anyone figured out how to make AutoPreview work in 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The advanced fine feature is very handy. MS hid the auto preview function very well. Here is how I found it. First, open and advanced find window.  Below the grayed area are the search columns, such as from or subject (I am sure the MS “engineers” attack on him for it).  Right clinic anywhere in the blue bar.

At the bottom of the pop up dialogue box is a selection for "view settings”.  Select that.  Another dialogue box appears titled Advanced View Settings etc.  Select the button titled `Other Settings…` (5th one down, with text Fonts and other Table etc…). There is a section entitled AutoPreview.  Change the  selection from `No AutoPreview` to `Preview all items` etc.  Hit OK to close that box.  Hit OK to close the next box.

This should now add AutoPreview to the Advanced Find search function in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

## Whole message

If you mean the Reading Pane for the whole message basically follow the instructions underneath to turn the preview on, and to *turn classic indentend conversation view off*.
(At least in Outlook 2016, this seems to block the preview when searching the "Current Mailbox" instead of the "Current Folder".)

#### Turn preview on, and turn conversation view off, using "View Settings"

(based on [Tim Carlson's answer](https://superuser.com/a/364867))

- open view settings:

  - in view-ribbon (view-menu-tab) click on "view settings", or
  - right-click empty area below the search results (scroll down), 
    and select "view settings"
- click on "Other Settings..."
- underneath "Reading Pane" check either "Right", or "Bottom" ("Off" will hide it)
- underneath "Other Options" ***uncheck*** "Show conversation groups using Classic Indented View"

#### Turn classic indentend conversation view off using "Conversation Settings"

If your preview is already on, one can switch the classic indentend conversation view quicker, doing this:

- click the view-ribbon (view-menu-tab)
- click on the "Conversation Settings" pulldown
- uncheck "Use Classic Indentend View"

## First lines

If you mean the AutoPreview for the first few lines:

- click the view-ribbon (view-menu-tab)
- click on the Message Preview pulldown
- select one from: Off, 1 Line, 2 Lines, 3 Lines

## Customized search folder

Or you could [create a custom search folder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
with your ow view settings, like recommended [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2013_release/outlook-advanced-find-preview-pane/a8e3f5a9-3a47-4d9c-bdad-cc5e532b9b9d),
but to me that seems a bit over the top.